# Java: Syntax highlighting component keyevents

Tags: java, swing, text-editor, syntax-highlighting, jedit

I just met the lib [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/). And now I'm making a Java Editor with a run-button who runs the code without compiling. For the texteditor-component, I use the open-source [jEdit Syntax Package](http://syntax.jedit.org/). Here is a link with a demo: [link](http://explodingpixels.wordpress.com/2008/05/17/simple-syntax-highlighting/).

Now I wrote code that adds every time the user pressed enter automaticly added the same number of tabs like the previous line starts with. I tested that code in a simple `JTextArea` and works correctly. But it seems the keyevents are not working with the `JEditTextArea`
I put this JComponent in a `JPanel`.

The `JEditTextArea` is the editor-component in the lib. (Extends `JComponent`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JEditTextArea` doesn't behave like a normal swing `JTextComponent`. See the overridden `processKeyEvent` code in JEditTextArea - it specifically avoids the KeyListener stuff for performance.

The way I've added key handling logic to JEditTextArea is to subclass the `DefaultInputHandler` and override `addDefaultKeyBindings`, calling `addKeyBinding()`  with your desired bindings and logic.

Comment: It is nicd you found it. But I used another lib, a mutch better.
`jsyntaxpane-0.9.5-b27.jar` is the name.